# How to close panel popuped over editor in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

In Eclipse I work most of the time with the editors maximized (I have to work on tiny screen a little larger then my smart phone). So console and junit view are collapsed on the sides.

When a test runs or a something get printed to the console the apropriate view pops up as desired.

Up to previous version I could just hit ESC (I think) and the view would collapse back.

But with the current version (Juno) I can't close the view by keyboard and with the mouse I need multiple clicks without realy understand where I have to click.

So the questions are:

How can I close the up popping view by keyboard, preferrable with a single key press.

What exactly is the criteria for the view to close when using the mouse?

Comment: It seems to me, I have to click another panel/view to close a panel that has pop upped. Clicking an editor doesn't always work. Nor does pressing Escape. Annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The popped up console view does in fact close upon pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> if the console is *in focus* ... but it takes like three seconds for it to react.

Otherwise, <kbd>F12</kbd> seems to be the default *Activate Editor* key-binding.

Oh, Eclipse would be **so great** if there was just a tad more focus on usability.

Answer (score 2):

Set your  <kbd>Esc</kbd> to "Activate Editor" command in key perference.

[image]

Comment: *F12* is the key for that out-of-the-box. At least for the *Linux CDT Juno* download.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of the menu item *Activate on Failure/Error only* in the JUnit view menu? That avoids one of the two situations in the first place. Especially as even the icon of the JUnit view shows the red/green result of a test run.

Comment: yupp, know that. I actually like the views popping up. I just want to get them away again fast.